# jQuery date picker show half day blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker to show some blocked dates of apartments. I am just taking all the blocked dates into array and giving styles to all dates like this.

```
              for (i = 0; i < activeDays.length; i++) 
              {
                   if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,activeDays) != -1) {
                    return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', ''];
              }
```

CSS

```
<style>
  .css-class-to-highlight a{
   background-color : Red !important;
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   }
</style>
```

This is the result

[image]

And my requirement is I need to show first date and last date of the blocked dates as half available. which means half of the date in red color. How can I do it using css or javascript? any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at CSS3 gradient feature. I have created a sample gradient at [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#eaeeef+50,ff3236+50;Custom). Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply css's  **background : linear-gradient**  property to div as below:

```
.css-class-to-highlight a{
   background : linear-gradient(red 50%, green 50%);
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

You can even make beautiful gradients out of by calculating more colors and percentages. [link](http://css-tricks.com/striped-background-gradients/).

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pramodnikam1/S2FP9/)

Comment: I want to do it for first date and last date. But okay I will do it. Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me how can I apply that gradient diagonally?

Comment: @raghuveer999 -  there is no css option to do it diagonally. Other option is available to do it radially.